# How to get multiple input values with PHP when name attributes are the same?

Tags: php, fpdf

I would like to know how to get the input value from all my input fields if all inputs have the same name attribute. I'm also using the FPDF library and I need to insert every value in different cells. This is the code...

```php
$pieces = explode(" ", $description);

foreach ($_POST as $key=>$description) {

    if (substr($key,0,6) === "field_"){
        $pdf->Cell(100,10, "$description", 1, 0, "L");
        $pdf->Cell(25,10,"$description",1,0,"C");
        $pdf->Cell(25,10,"$ $description",1,0,"L");
        $pdf->Cell(0,10,"$ $description",1,1,"L");
    }
}
```

My HTML is the following:

```html
<div class="input_fields_wrap" id="input_fields">
    <div class="new">
        <input class="description" maxlength="255" name="field_0" placeholder="Enter Description" type="text" value="">
        <input class="rate qty" data-rate="rate" maxlength="255" name="field_0" placeholder="0" size="5" type="text" value="">
        <input class="pack price" data-price="price" maxlength="255" name="field_0" placeholder="$ 0.00" size="5" type="text" value="">
        <input class="amount" id="amount" name="field_0" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in my PHP I even used the explode function but I don't get good results.

This is before the PDF

[image: This is before the PDF]

And this is what the PDF looks like

[image: And this is what the PDF looks like]

Thank you!.

Comment: When using checkboxes you can use an array input which looks like this, `<input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="apple"> <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="banana">`. But I'm not sure if that works for non-checkbox inputs as I'm a bit rusty on my PHP. Despite this, I would try to name your fields more appropriately. Why not use `description`, `rate` and `price` as field names?

Comment: If you're writing the html form yourself, why are you naming all the inputs with the same name? Surely the easiest solution is to not do that?

Comment: Rename name attributes. I don't know why would you use same name for different text inputs.

Comment: Ok I will try using different name attributes. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get all the input fields values using the **same name** `name="field_0"`. Instead make the `name` attribute of input fields like this, `name="field[0][]"`.

Your **HTML** code should be like this:

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap" id="input_fields">
    <div class="new">
        <input class="description" maxlength="255" name="field[0][]" placeholder="Enter Description" type="text" value="">
        <input class="rate qty" data-rate="rate" maxlength="255" name="field[0][]" placeholder="0" size="5" type="text" value="">
        <input class="pack price" data-price="price" maxlength="255" name="field[0][]" placeholder="$ 0.00" size="5" type="text" value="">
        <input class="amount" id="amount" name="field[0][]" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is how you can process the input field values in order to display them in PDF document.

```
$width_array = array(100, 25, 25, 0);
$pos_array = array(0, 0, 0, 1);
$align_array = array('L', 'C', 'L', 'L');
foreach ($_POST['field'][0] as $key => $description) {
    $pdf->Cell($width_array[$key],10, "{$description}", 1, $pos_array[$key], $align_array[$key]);
}
```

---

**Sidenote:** Like this `name="field[0][]"`, you might have another set of input fields which you can name them, `name="field[1][]"`